# What is the date of this family portrait from Pennsylvania?

Tags: photo-dating

I am looking for help dating this photograph. The man is my great-great grandfather Thomas Ryan, born in Pennsylvania in 1855, died 1926. I am fairly certain that the older woman is his mother (born 1820, Ireland, died 1912 Pennsylvania). The younger woman and the child, I believe to be his wife (1855-1894, Pennsylvania) and oldest child (a son, born 1877). The part that makes me uncertain is the clothing and hairstyes of the younger woman and the child. To me they look like the clothing of circa 1900 or even a little later, but I am certain of the wife's death date of 1894. Could this be dated slightly later and be a photo of their youngest son (born 1887, photo perhaps 1889?). Then I'm not sure why they wouldn't have included the older six children born between 1877-1887. If these people are not Thomas' wife and child, it's difficult to think of who they might be or why they would be significant enough relatives to include in a photograph. Perhaps I am overthinking it and this clothing is perfectly appropriate for the late 1870s. Thanks in advance for any thoughts or help with this conundrum.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE! I too think the photo is later, circa 1900. Could the unknown persons be a daughter and his first grandchild?

Comment: Thank you! Thomas had three surviving daughters (born 1879, 1880, and 1889) but none of them had kids. His two surviving sons had children in 1908, 1916, 1917, and 1923. The grandchild of 1908 was the only grandson and it would fit with the time frame but with the father being alive, why would only the (unrelated) mother be in the photo? It's a puzzle!

Comment: Not an answer, but a clue perhaps to help you narrow it down. 
The picture looks like it was taken in the summertime. With young children in the picture, I sometimes use the time of year (summertime) and the child's approximate age to narrow down which child might be in the picture.
So if you guess that the child is 12 months old, you'd eliminate any children that were born during a winter from consideration.

Comment: That's great advice, thank you!

Comment: To me, this looks very much like  an 1880 - 1900 photo, and I'm thinking closer to 1900. You might want to take a look at the resources from the UVM Landscape Change Program (https://www.uvm.edu/landscape/dating/index.php) - there's lots on clothing and hairstyles. This website (http://bartoscollection.com/vehairstylesbyera/hairstylesedwardian.html) shows a number of Edwardian (1901-1910) hairstyles, and to my very unfashionable eye, they look similar to the younger woman's hair.

Comment: Also, don't dismiss the possibility of it being extremely distant relatives, or even friends - I have a photo of my great-grandfather's second cousin. We never would have known who it was if it wasn't labeled. And we have a pair of wonderful late Victorian photos, one of a man and one of a woman, apparently on their wedding day. No one has any idea who they are.

Comment: 1909 would fit both the known dates and the hair- and clothing styles; perhaps the father of the child was the photographer, and that's why he's not in the picture?

Comment: If you know the families of the sons' wives, you might be able to find family photos of theirs that could be matched with the young woman.

Comment: Thank you for the info and opinions, everyone. Seems like Edwardian era is the consensus. Only Thomas' oldest son had a son (November 1908), his younger son had three daughters, later (beginning in 1915) and I have positive photos of all of them that do not resemble this child. To me this looks like a little boy, and yes, I suppose the woman would be the boy's mother. I am not in touch with anyone on that family branch but I have contacted someone on Ancestry.com who has the mother as a part of their tree so maybe that will provide a photo. I appreciate everyone taking the time to comment!

Comment: My wife says the woman's shirt waist went out with WW1 so somewhere between 1890 and 1914, probably closer to 1900.